# Bigger is better, but how do I make sure my PictureBoxes are resized relative to resolution?

Tags: c#, .net, layout, resize, picturebox

We have a bunch of forms with alot of PictureBoxes on them. They're basically a representation of an engineering system with pipes connected to pumps and whatever. Each element is it's own picturebox, so there's a few hundred.

The problem we have is that when we take the app to a large 40"+ TV, there's too much space everywhere and it doesn't look the way it does on the developer's screen. So we designed it for these large TV's but when we look at it on a normal computer screen it's all wrong.

So how do we design the form with pictureboxes for the actual images to resize and reposition the controls relative to the size of the resolution it's being viewed on? If we simply anchor everything then the image sizes themselves are not relative to the display it's seen on.

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a Winforms solution you will have to do at least some of the resize calculations if anchoring and docking do not provide you with the required results.

If it is really important to you to be able to design the UI in Visual Studio I recommend writing custom controls that expose the desired resize properties and resize behavior and perhaps even a custom designer to support the design time features.

It might not be feasible but you could consider having a look at WPF, it has a [ViewBox control](http://miteshsureja.blogspot.nl/2011/11/viewbox-in-wpf.html) that might simply be the answer to your needs.

Comment: Thanks, WPF has great scaling capability out of the box. I'll look into it.